# Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc, dsn

I am trying to connect to SQL database slightly different ways: with and without use of parameter. Why without use of parameters works fine, but with use of parameters - gives me an error. 
Did I make a syntax error? 
I went through each letters and couldn't see anything.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

#parameters:
server = 'SQLDEV'
db = 'MEJAMES'

#Create the connection
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};server =' + server + ';DATABASE = ' + db + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;')
# query db
sql = """

select top 10 PolicyNumber, QuoteID, ProducerName from tblQuotes

"""
df = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)
df
```

The statement above gives me an error [image]

But if I do the same but without use of parameters then it works fine:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

#parameters:
#server = 'SQLDEV'
#db = 'MEJAMES'

#Create the connection
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};server=SQLDEV;database=MEJAMES;Trusted_Connection=yes;")
# query db
sql = """

select top 10 PolicyNumber, QuoteID, ProducerName from tblQuotes

"""
df = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)
df
```

[image]

Comment: Try removing the space after the `server` keyword, i.e., `... ;server=' + server + ...` instead of `... ;server =' + server + ...`.

Comment: It worked. I cant believe python is sooo picky language. I wouldn't even think about that. Can you answer it and I'll accept as correct.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That would be SQLServer that's picky in this case, not Python, not that it matters..

Comment: @thebjorn - Actually, it's the Windows ODBC Driver Manager that's the culprit, not the SQL Server ODBC driver. The same thing will happen with any other ODBC driver.

Comment: @GordThompson cool, I've learned something new today :-)

Comment: should we make a /etc/odbcinst.ini too? https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Linux

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Windows ODBC Driver Manager is quite fussy about keywords in connection strings. They must be immediately followed by the equal sign, so `SERVER=...` will work, but `SERVER =...` will not.

Answer (score 2):

Its crazy but I managed to solve it by actually passing an option: extra_params: server=WHEREYOURSERVERLIVES\DBSERVER

I am using it pyodbc on django BTW.

Must be some bug.

something like this

```
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'YOURGREATESTDATABASE',
    'USER': 'YOURGREATESTUSERNAME',
    'PASSWORD': 'YOURGREATESTPASSWORD',
    'HOST': 'WHEREYOURSERVERLIVES\DBSERVER',
    'PORT': '',

    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        'extra_params': "Persist Security Info=False;server=WHEREYOURSERVERLIVES\\DBSERVER"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this format:

This should work

```
connection = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.4.so.2.1};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s"
                            % (server, database, username, password))
```

Comment: I think the main misunderstanding is confusing ODBC connection strings with whatever you're used to using, thanks for this.